# How to get certain variables in a file

Tags: java

If I have a file with 2 lines and the first line was split by BookType#BookName#Date and the second line was BookType#BookName#Date, how would I get the date of the first line specifically if I set a variable named 'date' to both the date of the first line and second line. (This is assuming the date in the first line and line field are different)

```
if (fields[0].equals("A"))
{
    ur.setBookType(fields[0]);
    ur.setBookName(fields[1]);
    ur.setDate(fields[2]);
}
else if (fields[0].equals("B"))
{
    ur.setBookType(fields[0]);
    ur.setBookName(fields[1]);
    ur.setDate(fields[2]);
```

The example of the file is

```
A#James and the Giant Peach#01-20-2013
B#Harry Potter#02-20-1990
```

Comment: I cannot understand your question.  It is especially not making sense for "set a variable ... to both the date".  Show us a concrete example and what you have tried.

Comment: Okay I edited it, sorry.

Comment: Could you please show your input file and your expected output?

Comment: Yup, I added in the expected output

Comment: The edited question still does not make sense... What is the expected behavior of your program? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm asking how would I get the date from the first line (book type "A") if the dates were different but the same variable (String date;) was used for the setter for both the setDate fields in the first and second line. I want to get the date because I want to compare both of them like A.getDate == B.getDate. I tried to make a different setter/getter for both like set/getADate and set/getBDate, but that did not work.

Comment: I see a better design. Here there is no change of steps executed and independent of condition. I assume this is the sample. Best part is create an ArrayList of class ur type and add all lines as objects to that ArrayList. Next you can compare individual object entities line by line iterating through the ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to get the dates per line? the question is not clear, but if it is you could use the code below.

```
int LastNoSignPosition = line.lastIndexOf("#");
String date = line.substring(LastNoSignPosition+1, line.length());
```

Then loop on the next line item.

EDIT:

```
int firstNoSign = line.indexOf("#"); //get position of 1st #
int secondNoSign = line.indexOf("#", firstNoSign+1); //get position of 2nd #
int thirdNoSign = line.indexOf("#", secondNoSign+1); //get position of 3rd #

String date = line.substring(thirdNoSign, thirdNoSign+10);
```

The +10 is assuming the date is always on the same format dd-mm-yyyy which is 10 character, if not get the forth number sign. Add a catch for out of bound when date or # is not present.

Comment: Sorry, not every line has a date. I was just putting those 2 as an example. These are the only ones with dates and the lines after them are just extra data. So its line 1, extra data, line 2, extra data

Comment: Will there always be 3 number sign per line to represent the type,name, date when if they don't have a value? Like BookType#BookName##?

Comment: Well for the 2 I posted, it will always be that same format of bookType,bookName,Date... for the data in the middle it will be 5 #.

Comment: can you provide samples where there are 5 #? is the date always after the third?

Comment: Yes, the date is always in the same spot (field 2). An example of extra data is Author#Stock#TimesRented#TotalTimesRented#TimesRentedWeek#TimesRentedMonth